# R creating sample from ffdf object

Tags: r

I have an ffdf object that has ~ 100 million rows of which I'd like to create a sample with ~ 5 million rows.

I used the following code but am not having any luck:

```
    > library(ffbase)
    > library(ff)
    > rowSamp1 <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11)
    > ff1 <- ff(runif(20))
    > ff2 <- ff(runif(20))
    > ff3 <- ff(runif(20))
    > ffdf1 <- ffdf(ff1, ff2, ff3)
    > dim(ffdf1)
    [1] 20  3
    > ffdf2 <- ffdf(ffdf1[rownames(ffdf1) %in% rowSamp1,])
    Error in as.hi.integer(x, maxindex = maxindex, dim = dim, vw = vw, pack = pack) : 
      NAs in as.hi.integer
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ffdf1[bigsample(x=100000000, size=5000000, replace = FALSE), ]